# Как поменять блоки местами без правки html?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть резиновый блок со старой(зачеркнутой) и новой ценой. Как поменять цены местами, чтобы сначала была новая, а потом старая без правки `html`, чтобы блоки оставались резиновыми и по располагались по центру страницы? [фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/y84m62af/)

```css
.price {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 25px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="price"><del><span class="amount">20.170 <ruble title="руб.">руб</ruble></span></del>
  <ins><span class="amount">19.162 <ruble title="руб.">руб</ruble></span></ins>
</div>
```

Comment: .price > del{
  float: right;
}

Comment: @soledar10 а результат вы видели? я же пишу - надписи должны быть точно также по центру

Comment: вот пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/fbrmzmkc/

Comment: @soledar10 оу, а вот это супер - спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Про FlexBox: на [русском](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/) и [английском](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Поддержка FlexBox [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

[image: Поддержка FlexBox]

## 1

[#order](http://frontender.info/a-guide-to-flexbox/#codeordercode)

Применяется к: дочернему элементу / flex-элементу.

По умолчанию flex-элементы располагаются в исходном порядке. Тем не менее, свойство order может управлять порядком их расположения в контейнере.

```css
.price {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.price ins {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
      -ms-flex-order: 1;
          order: 1;
}

.price del {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -webkit-order: 2;
      -ms-flex-order: 2;
          order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <del>
    <span class="amount">
      20.170 
      <ruble title="руб.">руб</ruble>
    </span>
  </del>
  <ins>
    <span class="amount">
      19.162 
      <ruble title="руб.">руб</ruble>
    </span>
  </ins>
</div>
```

## 2

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.price {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.price ins {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0 25px;
}

.price del {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <del>
    <span class="amount">
      20.170 
      <ruble title="руб.">руб</ruble>
    </span>
  </del>
  <ins>
    <span class="amount">
      19.162 
      <ruble title="руб.">руб</ruble>
    </span>
  </ins>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.price {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 25px;
  display: block;
}

.price {
  direction: rtl;
}

.price > * {
  display: inline-block;
  direction: ltr;
}
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <del><span class="amount">20.170 <ruble title="руб.">руб</ruble></span></del>
  <ins><span class="amount">19.162 <ruble title="руб.">руб</ruble></span></ins>
</div>
```

Comment: круто! а что такое `direction: ltr;` ?

Comment: @Вася, это направление письма right to left и left to right.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("del").each(function(){
    var div = $(this).parent('div');
    div.find('ins').insertBefore($(this))
});
```

[обновил ваш фидл](https://jsfiddle.net/y84m62af/5/)

Без jquery

```
   dels = document.getElementsByTagName('del'); 
   for (var i = 0; i < dels.length; i++)
        dels[i].parentNode.insertBefore(dels[i], dels[i].next);
```

Comment: подключать `jQuery` ради перемещения одного блока мне кажется нелогичным решением

Comment: не факт, что у него там этого jquery не полно уже :)

Comment: @lexxl вы знаете решение без скриптов? я весь во внимании

Comment: @splash58 если не будет другого решения без скрипта - я засчитаю ваше решение как правильное

Comment: написал в ответе вариант без jquery :)  там почти тоже самое

Comment: @splash58 спасибо, но это все равно скрипт) у ребят на чистом `css` получилось, так что сорри..)

Comment: это я писал в ответ на комментарий lexxl , собственно :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Если просто средствами css, то можно использовать flex, там revert делается в одну строку.
```

```css
.price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  flex-direction: row-reverse; //переставляет блоки в ряд
  //flex-direction: column-reverse; //переставляет блоки в столбик
}
```

```html
<div class="price">
  <del><span class="amount">20.170 <ruble title="руб.">руб</ruble></span></del>
  <ins><span class="amount">19.162 <ruble title="руб.">руб</ruble></span></ins>
</div>
```